# Class passing itself to constructor of other class, both defined with templates

Tags: c++, templates

Class `A` (or specializations thereof) should create instances of class `B` (or specializations thereof), where the latter has a field to know who created it. The following code isolates the problem:

```
template <typename R>
class A {
public:
  R make() { return R(this); }
};

template <typename S>
class B {
public:
  S * s;
  B(S * s_) : s(s_) { }
};
```

The challenge is the cyclic dependency of the template parameters. One solution appears with forward declaration:

```
class specB;
typedef A<specB> specA;
class specB : public B<specA> { using B::B; };
```

This works fine (using `specA` and `specB` in the rest of the program), as far as I can tell. However, the following does *not* (the missing `using` is not responsible, above I only included that in order that the extended constructor of `B` is found):

```
class specA;
typedef B<specA> specB;
class specA : public A<specB> { };
```

It gives:

```
In instantiation of ‘R A<R>::make() [with R = B<specA>]’:
   required from here
error: invalid conversion from ‘A<B<specA> >* const’ to ‘specA*’ [-fpermissive]
   R make() { return R(this); }
               ^
error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘B<S>::B(S*) [with S = specA]’ [-fpermissive]
   B(S * s_) : s(s_) { }
   ^
```

Is there a possibility to make it work this way as well (without `-fpermissive`)?

**Update**: here is a possible solution (seems to work), but it does not look right to me:

```
template <typename S>
class B {
public:
  S * s;
  B(void * s_) : s(static_cast<S*>(s_)) { }
};
```

Comment: Note that class `B` does not require its template parameter to be declared beforehand, but class `A` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a method of a base class is called through a derived class that method gets `this` as a pointer to the base class. The implementation of the base class cannot know of classes that are derived from it.

In the second example a `class A<B<specA>>` is created and a class `specA` inherits it. When you call `specA.make()` it calls `B<specA>(this)` with `this` being of type `A<B<specA>>*`. The compiler complains as the constructor of `B<specA>` expects an argument of type `specA*`. There is no trivial conversion from a base class pointer to a derived class pointer.

You can do it this way:

```
template<typename T>
class Alloc
{
    public:
    T make() { return T(*this); }
};

template<template<typename> class A>
class Type
{
    private:
    A<Type>* a_;

    public:
    Type(A<Type>& a): a_(&a) { }
};

Alloc<Type<Alloc>> a;
Type<Alloc> t(a);
```